# Postgres execute dynamic anonymous block in an anonymous block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How could I execute in PostgreSQL pl/pgSQL an anonymous block from a string?
There is [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), but it doesn't seem to accept a **begin-end** block as command-string (or I couldn't figure out how)

```
do $$
declare
  myBlock := 'begin null; end;';
begin
  execute myBlock;
end;
$$

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "null"
LINE 1: begin null; end;
              ^
QUERY:  begin null; end;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

And there is [do](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html), but it only accepts a string literal, no variables (and thus doesn't feel very useful inside a pgsql block...)

```
do $$
begin
  do 'begin null; end;';
end;
$$
```

But the code block to be executed is fetched from a table, thus do won't do.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? This smells like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: It doesn't strike me as an X-Y problem. I can see that there are a lot of use cases, where you can use this approach for the wrong reason, but I'm pretty confident there are legit cases (including mine) when you actually want to execute a dynamic sql, for which the documentation is quite clear when it's a select or update, but there is no example (or at least I couldn't find any), if it's an anonymous block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run another DO block in the dynamic SQL string:

```
do $$
declare
  myBlock text := 'do $nested$ begin raise notice $m$Hello$m$; end; $nested$';
begin
  execute myBlock;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Gee, thank you.
When I attempted the nested DO, I've put a hyphen in the $ quoting, 
'do $job-entry-0$ begin ... end; $job-entry-0$', which yielded a /syntax error at or near "$"/ on the first $ thus I abandoned that attempt. Thank you!